# Jquery result is splitted

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I get data from a page by this code :

```
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                data:
        {
            term: request.term
        },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui){
        $('#userselect').val(ui.item.id);
    }
    });             

});
```

the returned result is correct but when it display in my textbox, it splitted character by character like

```
[
{
"
i
d
```

and etc.

Comment: You are missing dataType in ajax call

Comment: it's fixed by : $(function() {
    
    //autocomplete
    $(".auto").autocomplete({
        source:  'search.php',
        select: function(event, ui){
        $('#athlete').val(ui.item.id);
    },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            $("#athlete").val('');
        }
    });             

});

Answer (score 0):

`ui.item` is an object.

Try referencing `ui.item.value`:

> [ui.item]: An Object with label and value properties for the selected option.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select